# Set Discount Price on Product detail page

Tags: product, price

I am developing a module where I need to set discounted price for a product if applicable. Admin will set a discount percent from backedn for a product and based on that the product price will be calculated.

For ex:

```
Product Price = 299
Discount Percent = 20%
Discounted Price = 239.20
```

So the price for that product will be `239.20`. I have displayed the discounted price successfully on listing page and the file changes is

```
catalog/product/list.phtml
```

But now I also need to change the price on product detail page. The file being used to display the price is

```
catalog/product/price.phtml
```

I do not want to change the `.phtml` file as it has number of conditions for price display.

[image]

What is the best method to set the discounted price on product detail page ?

I hope my question is clear.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: for Special Price you can use Magento Special price Functionality

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: @Jordan Why are you not using catalog price rule ?

Comment: For that if admin changes the discount percent, I again have to make changes in price rules. Also I have to specify SKU's everytime. Currently admin is selecting the products from my custom module

Comment: How are you getting the price on the product listing page?

Comment: Based on the discount percent applied for a product, I am calculating the price and when user clicks on add to cart, using an observer I am setting the discounted price in cart

Comment: Where you set the discount from system config or in any other else?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has the ability to display the special price when it is set on a product:

[image]

This is styled in the Magento frontend with the markup

```
<p class="special-price">
    <span class="price-label">Special Price</span>
    <span class="price" id="product-price-423">$224.00</span>
</p>
```

So using the following CSS should allow you to style it how you see fit:

```
.special-price .price { 
   /* your rules here */
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I know the special price settings, but I have a custom module that applies discount on a product and that discounted price will be shown in the special price HTML format as you have shown above.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are expecting from us so we can give you proper guidance.

Comment: If a product falls under a deal, it will have a discounted price which will be shown on listing as well as detail page. I am not sure how to display it on details page as it has number of `setPrice()` conditions. Discount price is not special price.

Comment: Have you created a new attribute with a type of price? If so you can display this just about anywhere in the product templates with `$this->getProduct()->getMySpecialPrice()` or something akin to that

Comment: No, admin will give discount percent on a deal and based on that I am calculating the price on frontend. This does not includes any attribute creation but simply specifying discount percent from backend.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm struggling to understand the requirements. Without a substantial update to your original question including the business case for the customization I'll be forced to close this question. Please revise and provide much more information. Thanks!

Comment: Pls see my updated question

Comment: any solution you propose ?